# font-variation-settings in jQuery .css

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a span for each letter (lettering.js). The font I use is a variable font.
Every time I hover the span, the "wght" (font weight) has to change randomly between 20-500 wght's.
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".letter").hover(function(){
      var varwght = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 20);
      var xstyles = {"font-variation-settings: \'wght\'" varwght};
      $(this).css(xstyles);
  });
});
```

this does not work. I guess it's because of "font-variation-settings: \'wght\'" varwght
How can I solve this? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `{"font-variation-settings: \'wght\'" varwght}` This is invalid js code. Try to fix this first

Comment: `{"font-variation-settings": "\'wght\'" varwght}`

Answer (score 0):

You are just concatenating your string incorrectly. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".letter").hover(function() {
      var varwght = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 20);
      var xstyles = {"font-variation-settings": "'wght' " + varwght};
      $(this).css(xstyles);
  });
});
```